# textview adding new text after /n doesn't match textview.textAlignment

Tags: ios, core-data, textview

I have a textview that is center aligned, ie. s`elf.textView.textAlignment is NSTextAlignmentCenter` (as set in IB and confirmed in debug area).

I automatically create the text for the textView from 3 different strings and use a new line break /n between the three strings:

```
NSString *string1 = @"Hello";
NSString * string2 = @"Nice weather isn't it";
NSString *string3 = @"Bye";

self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@ \n %@", string1, string2, string3];
```

So this produces a textview that shows 3 lines of text that is center aligned.
If the user puts the curser at the end of any of the lines and hits return, the new line will be left aligned - NOT center aligned per textView.textAlignment.  If the user puts the curser in the middle of any line and hits return, the new line will be center aligned.

Why is this happening?  If I use /r (carriage return) instead of /n, any new line will be center aligned - great but if I save the final text as the new input to the textView (e.g. save the self.textView.text as text in core data and then load a textview with this text), it acts as if it still contains /n and new lines of text are not center aligned.   When I look at the text in SQLite, I can't see the characters for the /n - if I did I could change substitute /r for /n when I load the text.  How can I reload the text with /r between the lines or otherwise have any edits or new text be center aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the special character on the fly with something like:

```
let stringToDisplay = String(originalString.characters.map {$0 == "\n" ? "\r" : $0 })
```

Objective-C

```
NSString *stringToDisplay = [originalString 
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\r"];
```

Comment: Thanks - this works - only changes would be to use @"\n" and @"\r" in the obj-c code.  I can now save and reopen text with within the textview and maintain textAlignment.  Now my problem is updating the textview while new lines of code are entered.  Return implicitly adds \n to the end of the line.  If you hit return a few times, the first row is center aligned but others are left aligned.  I've tried updating textView.text using textView: textViewDidChange: or textView: shouldChangeTextInRange:range:replacementText: but could get textview to update.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Apple Technical Support said that this problem is a bug and to file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back on this! Good we also found  workaround for now. - You should accept the answer (by ticking the check mark).